# gwt remote procedure call error

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, web

I am new to GWT and I have no result from my web application.

when I tried debugging, I got an error like "source not found"

and here is the code written in all the project

<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

EntryPoint Class

```
package body.test.combo.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;


public class Combo implements EntryPoint {


    private final FileReaderServiceAsync serviceAsync = GWT
            .create(FileReaderService.class);

    String content;

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {

    VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        serviceAsync.readMyFilePlease(new AsyncCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                content = result;

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                System.out.println("Tezak");

            }
        });

        Label lb = new Label(content);
        vPanel.add(lb);
        RootPanel.get().add(vPanel);
    }
}
```

<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

Service Interface

```
package body.test.combo.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("readmeplease")
public interface FileReaderService extends RemoteService {
    String readMyFilePlease();
}
```

<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

Service Async

```
package body.test.combo.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface FileReaderServiceAsync {
    void readMyFilePlease(AsyncCallback<String> callbackVariable);
}
```

<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

Server Implementation class

```
package body.test.combo.server;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

import body.test.combo.client.FileReaderService;

public class FileReaderServiceImplementation extends RemoteServiceServlet implements FileReaderService {

    @Override
    public String readMyFilePlease() {
        String allContent = "ezayak yad ya sayed";
        return allContent;
    }

}
```

<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>readMyFilePlease</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>body.test.combo.server.FileReaderServiceImplementation</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>readMyFilePlease</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/combo/readmeplease</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Combo.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Project name is 'combo'.

Comment: ...and the error itself? Does it cause an error in both dev mode and compiled Javascript?

Comment: please paste the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Does your project xml file (Combo.gwt.xml) contain the following:

`<module rename-to='combo'>`

You may also want to try some of the suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775106/gwt-rpc-service-not-found).

it would be very useful for you to post that project xml file as well as the error itself.

Comment: it doesnot contain <module rename-to='combo'> and when i add it nothing change

Comment: Did you put `<module rename-to='combo'>` in the existing module tag? Can you post the Combo.gwt.xml file?

Comment: There are also possible fixes here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401081/gwt-compiler-cant-find-gwt-xml